# Does the Scrum process ultimately divest team members from their respective skills?

Tags: scrum

My organization has been experimenting with the introduction of more "Agile" methods.  We've been trying the Scrum approach for a short while, and most of the team has, more or less, adapted to it.  I like it as a whole, but I'm concerned about one potentially severe impact of the methodology: as teams are consistently focused on features and backlog items, and testers are more integrated with the overall development process, it seems like skill sets are becoming blurred, and people are sensing less respect for their individual abilities.

Some of our developers are excellent at server-side technologies and optimization of heavy-weight data provisioning.  Others have invested a large amount of their careers learning GUI technologies and have developed a fundamental understanding of users and usability in an application.  Neither skill set is better than the other, but they are certainly different.

Is this an inevitable result of the Scrum process?  Since everyone on the team (as I understand it) contributes to satisfying the next feature/requirement, backlog item, or testing goal at hand, the underlying philosophy seems to be "anyone can do it."  This is, in my experience, simply not true.  Most engineers (developers, testers, etc.) have a particular skill set they have honed over the years, and the Scrum methodology, in my mind, tends to devalue those very abilities they were previously respected for.

Here's an example for clarification:

If a sudden change of technology occurs on the server-side data provisioning, and every item on the to-do list for the sprint is based on this new change, the GUI developers (who likely haven't had time to become acclimated with the new technology) might not be able to contribute to the sprint.  At the very least, they will need to invest time to get ramped up, and then their code will be suspect because of their lack of experience.

I understand the need for rapid development to discourage "role silos" but doesn't this discount one fundamental reality: people develop *skills* in accordance to necessity, their interests, or their experiences.  People seem to be less motivated when they perceive their position is one of "plug-ability" (e.g. we can "plug" anyone in to do this particular task).  How does Scrum address this?  If it doesn't, has anyone addressed this when adopting the Scrum methodology?

Comment: +1 for a very insightful analysis. I wish my first scrum master would have understood that developers aren't just developers but experts in specific areas and that it is not bad thing but a good thing.

Comment: I think that some people might view it as a bad thing, at least in situations where you only have one or two people who are experts on a certain something and the company is screwed if those people ever leave.

Comment: I don't think either view on specialization (good or bad) is valid or invalid, but just different viewpoints that you can have - it's a tradeoff like just about everything else. Although in the Agile world, some might say that having a more well-rounded team makes the org more agile as a whole.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The point of Scrum is for the developers to self-organize.  We use scrum where I am, and jobs get passively sorted by a person's focus.  We don't do it on purpose with a chart and list, it just happens.  We all know who's best at what, or what their main/secondary focuses are.  If the 'main' person needs help, they get the person/people with a secondary focus in it to help.  We do get plenty of tasks not necessarily in line with whatever our particular focus is, but you always know who to ask for help then.

For your example - I don't know that if you say had 3 server guys and 5 gui guys, that you'd expect to get all the work done in that sprint (if the server guys + some help from the others wasn't enough).  The way the sprint is supposed to work is that from a prioritized list, the developers pick what they think they can get done in that 30-day timeframe.  If that meant the GUI guys needed 2 days of server-side training in order to help, that's what it'd mean.  Unless there were concurrent things also high up the list that they could do instead.  The sprint tasks are not supposed to be dictated by management as a psuedo-deadline.

If you have a Safari account, there's an interesting mostly case-study book by one of the guy/s who invented scrum.

Comment: Thanks for the great response! Here's a question: what if the required training was much greater? What if the server-developers needed to learn a new language (e.g. Silverlight or Flex) because the GUIs no longer coded in the teams' original language?

Comment: The required training should be shown on the sprint backlog (team owns it) and estimated, as soon as it is discovered as a valid task. If it means that sprint cannot succeed because of that - you know you have a problem to deal with. Scrum doesn't solve problems. It just helps bringing them into the focus. You might end up with variety of solutions. Outsource some tasks, reduce sprint scope, ...

Answer (score 16):

The short answer is an emphatic **NO**! Scrum does *not* blur or depreciate the skills required for specialization. Scrum does not promote generalization.

The long answer is that in Scrum, the most important thing is to get the work "Done". The team, as a team (as opposed to a collection of individual "stars") collaborate, as needed, in order to get the job done. Whatever it takes - however they want (Scrum is about self managing, self motivating teams, right?).

What this means is that a scrum team may be composed of several specialists, who primarily do what they specialized in (DBA, Graphic Design, even technical writers). The team, as a whole, should have all of the skills required to fulfill the requirements. This is not the same as saying that each team **member** has to have all of the skills aforementioned.

That being said, it is often desired - often by the members themselves - that members other than the specialists be at least *adequate* in skills different from their specialty. Another poster already mentioned Scott Ambler's "General Specialist". This helps the team when there's too much work of one kind, when the specialist is absent, and it helps the member when he really would like to gain experience outside his specialty.

Given that the team is self organizing, if for some reason a specialist finds himself in the middle of the sprint, without any work to do in his specialty, the best way to deal with it, is to simply ask the specialist what he wants to do. Let the team decide. The specialist can decide to help in his other areas of *adequacy*, do a POC for the next sprint, "shore-up" the defenses by fixing some long forgotten technical debt, or shine the shoes of the members who *are* working.

Yup. I don't know if this is **the** long answer. But it definitely was **a** long answer.
:-)

Comment: I wish I could vote this up more than once.  Self-orginzing, choosing your own tasks in the sprint: people will do what they are interested in, until there is no more of that kind of work left... but work expands to fill time.  Ideally, people will challenge themselves and complete a task outside their comfort zone, but that can't be forced.  New hires or new members might always be working out of their comfort zone of course.

Comment: It is often tough to get someone to challenge himself outside of his comfort zone. I've got a programmer on my team, who "doesn't do GUI". I'm working on it, though...

Comment: what happens if you are the specialist, and for a given sprint there isn't anything for you to do, but the SCRUM master keeps asking you why you aren't working off the board?

Comment: A specialist doesn't necessary mean "incapable of working outside your area of specialty". In fact - it shouldn't. If the SM asks you that question, answer him. Tell him the truth. A good SM will guide you towards trying to extend yourself. Perhaps you can be of use to the team and its goals outside of your specialty? Perhaps you can pair with someone on a task that focuses on a skill you don't have but would like to have? Perhaps you are **Adequately** qualified to work on a task that isn't in your specialty? Can you think of anything else **of value** that the specialist can be doing?

Comment: #comfortzone: it is SM's job to identify opportunities and challenge the team/individuals to reach out of the comfort zone.

Answer (score 3):

I've been working as a ScrumMaster for about 18 months and have worked with two different teams. I initially expected to experience the potential issues you raise but this has not been the case. What I generally observe is that the team evolves into a mixture of specialists and generalists as people find the appropriate role for themselves - one that they can enjoy and be successful at. This is self-organisation at work. I have never had a case where our specialists were sitting idle.

If this did occur, I would expect it to be raised as an issue in Sprint Retrospective and the team would discuss how to improve the situation. The most obvious (and brutal) conclusion would be to change the team composition.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why skill set will get blurred. There is a fair amount of confusion in the agile world. Scrum is a project management process and not a software development process and should not be seen as one. The engineers have to follow their own methodologies like TDD or extreme programming to add their own part to being agile.

Nothing goes away in scrum.

PM's still document as they go
Architects still architect their components. The only thing is they just delay some major decisions to more responsible point in time.
Developers should still follow best practices such as [SOLID principles](http://www.codetoglory.com/?p=40) to enable for refactoring in a consistent manner as features change.

Answer (score 2):

I think Scott Ambler addresses this issue very thoroughly in http://www.agilemodeling.com/essays/generalizingSpecialists.htm...

His concept of a Generalizing Specialist is exactly the thing Collective Ownership / Scrum Team calls for, and makes total sense to me.

Its hard to achieve in real life though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you find for any reason ('sudden change of technology' or not) that the amount of work required for a system over a sprint is greater than the amount available then there's a problem with your scheduling.

One fix is that, as you suggest, you take programmers from other areas and throw them onto the mix. How well this works depends on the skills of that person and how different the problem domain is, but treating programmers as generic units that can be farmed out as needed is generally not a successful strategy for developing software.

This is still a scheduling problem though.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing about Scrum is exactly the fact that skills do get a bit blurred! The point is to avoid silos at all costs by spreading specialist knowledge across the team and letting people work a bit outside their comfort zone.

Obviously this is not for everybody. Some developers are happy in their own narrow specialist field and such people are more of a hindrance in a Scrum process than an asset, whereas well-rounded and multi-talented people who are determined to get the job done, usually adapt very very well to it and are far more productive.

One of the key benefits of Scrum is to get the whole team actually involved and invested into the project instead of tackling their own special tasks and then riding off to the horizon. I'd claim that for most people, this is a far more rewarding way of working than the conveyor belt -approach of waterfall processes.

So I'd advise to boldly embrace the mixing of skills and having people come together to take down nasty problems instead of relying on specialist silos. The result of teams consisting of motivated people can be surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this would lead to more well-rounded developers, and also allow those who are experts in certain areas to continue to contribute their expertise.

I haven't used Scrum much myself (yet), but from your description, these types of teams would lead to a team/organization that is also more well-rounded as a whole - and shouldn't that be the goal of any team?

Answer (score 0):

Handling sudden changes is part of Agile and this may mean that some people have to go off and learn new skills. Course this is more within the general Agile philosophy than anything Scrum-specific.  There may be some extreme cases where the customer or business decides to change the world by bringing in something new and thus has to handle the subsequent pain of those people ramping up but if this is what they want and the developers are overruled, then there are only a couple of choices: (Take your lumps and try to handle the major changes) or (quit and get out of there).

While there can be some cases where someone that has specialized in something may be able to do things faster, this doesn't necessarily mean much if that is just one person on the team that is an expert and there is enough work in that area for 10 people for the whole sprint.  Should those not an expert simply not do that work and let that one person attempt to get through as much as he or she can?  I don't think so but there should be something to be said for those that aren't the best at something still trying to get done what they can get done.